# Issue with Reactivity

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I have below code, in which I am facing trouble understanding reactivity

Below is my UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = sDashBordTitle
)

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "btnData",

        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel(title="Home Page",
                   tags$br(),
                   tags$br(),
                   tags$br(),
                   tags$br(),
            fluidRow(
              column(
                width=12,
                  box(
                    width = 12,title = sHomeDataTitle,status = "primary",solidHeader = T,collapsible = F,collapsed = F,


                    fluidRow(
                        column(width=2,
                              ###########Add some label here##########
                             div(id="BrandDiv","Brand Information",style="height:200px;font-size:200%;color:black;border-right:1px solid")
                             ),

                        column(width=4,
                                textInput(inputId="sIdBrandName",label="Enter the brand Name",width = "200px"),
                                actionBttn(inputId="btnAddBrandToList",label = "Add brand",style = "unite",color = "primary",size = "md"),
                                tags$br(),
                                tags$br(),
                                uiOutput("ddbBrandDropdDown")
                             ),

                        column(width=2,
                             div(id="InstanceDiv","Instance Information",style="height:200px;font-size:200%;color:black;border-right:1px solid")
                             ),

                        column(width=4,
                          ##########Add instance text box and instance dropdown############
                          textInput(inputId="sIdInstanceName",label="Enter the Instance Name",width = "200px"),
                          actionBttn(inputId="btnAddInstanceToList",label = "Add Instance",style = "unite",color = "primary",size = "md"),
                          tags$br(),
                          tags$br(),
                          uiOutput("ddbInsatnce")
                        )
                    ),

                    #############Adding row which will contains the OK button################
                    fluidRow(
                      column(width=12,
                             column(width=2),
                             column(width=6,
                                    actionBttn(inputId = "btnOK",label="Continue",style = "fill",color = "primary",size = "md",block = T)
                              ),
                             column(width=2)
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )     
            ),
          tabPanel(title="Permissions"
          )
       )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "btnSummary",
      h2("this if for summary")
    )
  )
)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader <- header,
    dashboardSidebar <- sidebar,
    dashboardBody <- body
  )
)
```

and below is server.R

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {




  observe({
    sNewBrand<<-input$sIdBrandName
    sNewInstance<<-input$sIdInstanceName
    sBrandNameSelectedInBrandNameDropDown<<-input$ddbBrandNameDropDown
  })



  ###############################################################
  # Below function creates the sidebar menu based on the booolean
  # Need to update the function 
  ###############################################################

  output$menu<-renderMenu({

    if(blnDisplaySideBar){
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(tabName = "btnData",text="Data",icon=icon("home")),
        menuItem(tabName = "btnSummary",text="Summary",icon=icon("bar-chart"))
      )
    }  
  })


  ##############################################################################################################################
  # Below function create the dropdown for the Brand, It filters the User-Brand-Scneario file on the logged in User Id
  # and uses the unique values of brand to populate the dropdown
  # Also, it removes empty string or NA from the dropdpwn if found in the file
  ##############################################################################################################################

  output$ddbBrandDropdDown<-renderUI({
    VBrandAccessibleByUser<-fcnReturnAccessibleBrandListByLoggedInUser()

    if(is.null(VBrandAccessibleByUser)){
      return(NULL)  
    }else{
      selectInput(inputId="ddbBrandNameDropDown",label = "Select Brand",choices = VBrandAccessibleByUser,width = "200px",
                  selected = VBrandAccessibleByUser[1])
    }

  })


  ##############################################################################################################################
  # Below function creates the dropdown for the Scenario. It filters the User-Brand-Scenario file on the logged in User Id and
  # the brand value selected in the brand dropdown and uses the unique values of scenarios to populate the dropdown
  # Also, it removes empty string or NA from the dropdown if found in the file
  # P.S- below function is also reactive as it depends on the input values of the brand dropdown
  ##############################################################################################################################

  output$ddbInsatnce<-renderUI({
    sBrandName<-input$ddbBrandNameDropDown

    vInstanceAccesibleByUser<-fcnReturnInstancesAccesibleByUserForABrand(sBrandName)

    if(is.null(vInstanceAccesibleByUser)){
      return(NULL)
    }else{
        selectInput(inputId = "ddbnstanceNameDropDown",label="Select Instance",choices=vInstanceAccesibleByUser,width="200px",
                    selected = vInstanceAccesibleByUser[1])
    }

  })






  #############################################################################################################################
  # Below observe event runs when the user clicks on Add brand button.
  # It then appends the added Brand value to the old list and also selects the added brand value in the dropdown
  # It does not do anything if Add brand button is clicked with no brand value in it  
  # Also, it updates the global brand data table with the user ID, Brand Name and Sceanrio fields with 
  # logged in User ID, entered brand Name and Null with the instance respecitively
  #############################################################################################################################


  observeEvent(input$btnAddBrandToList,
    {
      if(sNewBrand==""){
      }
      else{
        vBrandAccessibleByUser<-fcnReturnAccessibleBrandListByLoggedInUser()

        if(is.null(vBrandAccessibleByUser)){
          vNewChoices<-c(sNewBrand)

          output$ddbBrandDropdDown<-renderUI({
            selectInput(inputId = "ddbBrandNameDropDown",label = "Select Brand",choices = vNewChoices,
                        selected = sNewBrand)
          })          

        }else{
          vNewChoices<-append(vBrandAccessibleByUser,sNewBrand)
          updateSelectInput(session,"ddbBrandNameDropDown",label = "Select Brand",choices = vNewChoices,
                            selected = sNewBrand)
        }
        # updateSelectInput(session,"ddbBrandNameDropDown",label = "Select Brand",choices = vNewChoices,
        #                   selected = sNewBrand)


        ############Update the global brand data table########################3
        dtuserFileSceanrio<<-rbindlist(list(dtuserFileSceanrio,list(sLoggedInUser,sNewBrand,NA)))
        print("test")
        #write_csv(dtUpdated,"../Admin files/Userscenariomapping.csv")
      }  
    }
    )

  #############################################################################################################################
  # Below observe event runs when the user clicks on Add Instance button
  # It then appends the added instance valye to the old list and also selects the added instance value in the dropdown
  # It does not do anything if Add instance button is cliceked with no instance value in it
  # Also, it updates the global brand data table with the User ID, Brand Name and Scenario Name fields with
  # logged in User ID, brand name selected in brand name dropdown and entered instance name respectively
  #############################################################################################################################



    observeEvent(input$btnAddInstanceToList,
      {
        if( sNewInstance == "" || sBrandNameSelectedInBrandNameDropDown == "" ){
            return(NULL)
        }else{

            vInstanceAccesibleByUser<-fcnReturnInstancesAccesibleByUserForABrand(sBrandNameSelectedInBrandNameDropDown)

            if(is.null(vInstanceAccesibleByUser)){
              vNewInstanceChoice=c(sNewInstance)  

              output$ddbInsatnce<-renderUI({
                selectInput(inputId = "ddbnstanceNameDropDown",label = "Select Instance",choices = vNewInstanceChoice,
                            selected = sNewInstance)
              })

            }else{
              vNewInstanceChoice=append(vInstanceAccesibleByUser,sNewInstance)
              updateSelectInput(session,"ddbnstanceNameDropDown",label = "Select Instance",choices = vNewInstanceChoice,
                                selected = sNewInstance)
            }

            # updateSelectInput(session,"ddbnstanceNameDropDown",label = "Select Instance",choices = vNewInstanceChoice,
            #                   selected = sNewInstance)

            ############Update the global brand data table########################
            dtuserFileSceanrio<<-rbindlist(list(dtuserFileSceanrio,list(sLoggedInUser,sBrandNameSelectedInBrandNameDropDown,sNewInstance)))
            print("test")
           # write_csv(dtUpdated,"../Admin files/Userscenariomapping.csv")
        }                   
      }
    )

})
```

1) I am having hard time understand the code execution(order of function call) of server.R when the app is loaded.

2) If I change the `Brand`dropdown then my `instance` dropdown gets updated reactovely, However once the `observeevent` code is called for `Add brand` buttton then the reactivity between Brand dropdown and instance dropdown stops working

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Below is my global.R

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(readr)

sDashBordTitle<-"Market-Mix"
blnDisplaySideBar<-TRUE
sHomeDataTitle<-"Market-Mix"
sLoggedInUser<-"A"


############Source R scripts################
source("GenericCode.R")

##################Read the User-Brand-Scenario file################
dfuserFileScenario<-read_csv("../Admin files/Userscenariomapping.csv")
dtuserFileSceanrio<-as.data.table(dfuserFileScenario)

sNewBrand<-""
sNewInstance<-""
sBrandNameSelectedInBrandNameDropDown<-""
```

Comment: Where does function `actionBttn` come from? Where is object `blnDisplaySideBar` created? There appears to be several bugs in your code and I cannot run it.

Comment: `acctionbttn`  is a function under shinywidgets and blnDisplaySideBar is a boolean which has been declared under global.R

Comment: If global.R is essential to your app, you need to include it in your question as well.

Comment: @jsb Please see the edit

Comment: and now please add the code from `GenericCode.R` !!